# MPI program gets stuck on more than 2 processors

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

My code looks like below. I try to run it by using "mpiexec -n -4 ./name.exe" but it does nothing and just waits. It works for 2 processors. What is wrong with the code? The idea is that the process sends the rank * 10 to the next process and at the end last process sends rank*10 to rank 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()

{
    int rank, sent, size;

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);


    if (rank == 0) {
        int valueToSend = rank * 10;

        MPI_Send(&valueToSend, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv(&sent, 1, MPI_INT, size - 1, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        printf("Process %d otrzymal %d od %d\n", rank, sent, status.MPI_SOURCE);
    }
    else if (rank < size - 1)
    {
        int valueToSend = rank * 10;
        int sendToNumber = rank + 1;
        int receivedFromNumber = rank - 1;

        MPI_Send(&valueToSend, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv(&sent, 1, MPI_INT, receivedFromNumber, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        printf("Process %d otrzymal %d od %d\n", rank, sent, status.MPI_SOURCE);

    }
    else if (rank == size - 1) {
        int valueToSend = rank * 10;
        int receivedFromNumber = rank - 1;
        MPI_Send(&valueToSend, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv(&sent, 1, MPI_INT, receivedFromNumber, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        printf("Process %d otrzymal %d od %d\n", rank, sent, status.MPI_SOURCE);
    }

MPI_Finalize();
return (0);
}
```

Comment: Every process starts with a send. That is a blocking call, so you have deadlock. If it doesn't block in certain configurations that can be because your implementation uses "eager sends". You can not count on that without digging into the documentation for the details. In your particular case you can use `MPI_Sendrecv`, and more generally `MPI_Isend/Irecv`.

Comment: Compile with `-Wall` and address the local variable that is set but never used.

Comment: As a matter of style, you should really get rid of all the if and else, and instead use the modulo `%` operator and a single `MPI_Sendrecv()`.